# Blender — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

> **This has been shipped today!** Enjoy your swag, everyone :)
>
> If you still don't have yours and think you should have it by now, please send me an e-mail so I can look into it *instead of leaving a comment here*. :)

---

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: Hey I didn't know about this, I was unaware there were BSE prizes! Pretty cool :)

Comment: I have the same mailing address as another user on this site. Will it be a problem to have two packages coming to the same address?

Comment: I don't expect it to be a problem, no, @X-27.

Comment: Awesome, I'll submit my form :)

Comment: Yay! By the way, the logo pictured is the [wrong logo](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/969/599). I realize this is probably due to a recycling of the demo images of the original logo, but better safe than sorry ;)

Comment: To everyone getting some of this nice "swag" congratulations!

Comment: I am gonna wear it with pride!

Comment: Awesome, got an email out of the blue today offering free swag. Can't complain about that! :D

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Gonna be wearing this around. Not sure if anyone will recognize it though.

Comment: I've let our designers know, @gandalf3 (though I'm pretty sure it was an oversight ;)

Comment: Wow, cool!  Though the [lack of mousepads is dissapointing](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/969/updated-december-24-blender-site-design#comment4147_974) I'm looking forward to my t-shirt!

Comment: Eagerly awaiting my shirt, stickers and tablet! :)

Comment: Approximately how big are the stickers going to be, and how many are coming in the surprise pack?

Comment: The picture above gives you a sense of the stickers' size, @X-27. And we usually send 3 to each user, IIRC.

Comment: Dang... three pages away from Swag!

Comment: Serious question: If I fill out the form twice will I get two shirts?

Comment: Serious answer: nope :P

Comment: is the forms up yet cause I can't see them ?

Comment: You should have received an e-mail with a link to it, @Chebhou.

Comment: Hello! Has anyone recieved the shirt yet? Have they been shipped? No hurry, just asking, maybe mine sank in the ocean? :D

Comment: I don't believe these have been shipped yet, @RóbertLászlóPáli. I'll let you know once they have.

Comment: Thanks for notifying about status! As a warning, I started to receive spam mails from something calling itself FedEX failing to deliver parcel, which contain .zip with strong encoding trojain .crypted Ransomware. So be careful when checking these.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the update and also for the warning.

Comment: I was just loosing hope, here in Italy... :) I just wish they don't come in middle august, since I could not be at home, for the holidays...

Comment: @JNat Soo.. 15 weeks passed and no sign of the shipment. I will move to different address in a week, If the shipment wasn't shipped yet, I might need to change the shipping adress..

Comment: I'll check on the status of this, @Jerryno. In the meantime, you can always send me an e-mail with your new details.

Answer (score 6):

## My package has arrived!

[image: BSE shirt stickers and tablet!]

Thank you SE for my shirt stickers and [tablet](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/blender-top-user-swag#comment4481_1065)!

The shirt is greyer then expected.
The stickers are a little smaller then expected.
The tablet is completely unexpected!

I'm also glad to finally figured out the secret meaning behind [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/278094). It is not 6 to 8, but 6 **+** 8 weeks, meaning about 14 weeks (or in my case 16).

---

**Edit:** [this should help](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-title-attribute)

Comment: Did moderators get an Intuos? I'll trade you my stickers for the tablet !

Comment: We did not send tablets to anyone, no, @cegaton :P

Comment: How lucky you are you've got Intuos 4!. I've only got Intuos 2 in my package :(. Your answer made my day BTW :D.

Comment: @PaulGonet Glad to hear it made you smile. that was the main point.

Comment: @David My offer stands. I'll even throw in a CD with blender 2.68...

Comment: @JNat I've been meaning to say - I recently received my package. The shirt is even nicer than expected (love the color and material). Thank you guys so much for the awesome swag!

Comment: I got mine today... :D the t-shirt color is a little different, but my smile is big anyway, thanks!